# Pandas do something for all unique column values

Tags: python, pandas

Only just started using Panda's, so please excuse my ignorance.

Say I have a csv file with a number of row and columns:

```
ID, Name, Number, SomethingElse
1, John, 234234, "word"
2, Dave, 2342423, "word2"
3, John, 54365345, "word3"
```

I want to create a new csv with only unique values for Name. 
I am using:

```
unique = df.Name.unique()
```

To get a new DataFrame? with all the unique names, but I can't work out how to use this new DF to find each Name and create a new File with all the values for that name:

```
file1.csv
ID, Name, Number, SomethingElse
1, John, 234234, "word"
3, John, 54365345, "word3"

file2.csv
ID, Name, Number, SomethingElse
2, Dave, 234234, "word2"
```

Usually I would use a set, then nested loops in Python3, but I think i lack a fundamental understanding of what dataframes actually are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible change filename by `name` values for `John.csv` or `Dave.csv` loop by [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) object with [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
for i, g in df.groupby('Name'):
    g.to_csv(f'{i}.csv', index=False)
```

For lowercase filenames add `lower()`:

```
for i, g in df.groupby('Name'):
    g.to_csv(f'{i.lower()}.csv', index=False)
```

Also your solution is possible use with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering:

```
for v in df.Name.unique():
    df[df['Name'] == v].to_csv(f'{v.lower()}.csv', index=False)
```

---

Solution for `file1.csv`, `file2.csv` with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for j, (i, g) in enumerate(df.groupby('Name'), 1):
    g.to_csv(f'file{j}.csv', index=False)
```

Or:

```
for j, v in enumerate(df.Name.unique(), 1):
    df[df['Name'] == v].to_csv(f'file{j}.csv', index=False)
```